# 7z zip all folders within a directory to an individual zip file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, 7zip

i am making some progress, but still stuck

I have unzipped all 200 zip files.  now, I need to re-zip with the filename as the name of the folder.

I am trying:

C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z a  *.zip -wc:\users\xxx\documents\folder\TEST2\
 -spe

no joy. :(

Help?

Comment: Is there a reason that there is no space between `-w` and `c:`? What's the error you're getting.  You've also tagged this as a `batch-file` request.  Where's your full batch file code so we can edit/adjust for you?

Comment: i thought that 7z could do it, but the more i read, the more it seems to be something like a batch, which i am trying to write my first one

Comment: i gather something like this?

   @echo off
   Set Winrar=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip.7z.exe
   Set MyFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\FOLDER\TEST2\
   Set ArchiveName= -- i dont kow how to make a dynamic link to the foldername, which should be the file name
   "%Winrar%" a -r -afzip -ep1 -dh "%ArchiveName%" "%MyFolder%"
   pause

Comment: a coworker put on his cape and solved the problem.
SET "DataDIR=%cd%"
SET zippy=%DataDIR%\ELearning\%Name%.zip
SET zipper=".\7-ZipPortable\App\7-Zip\7z.exe"
 
for /F %%f in ('dir /B/D %DataDIR%\ELearning') do (
  start  /wait repair.bat %%~nf
)
pause
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO NOT-THERE
SET Name=%1
SET "DataDIR=%cd%"
SET zippy=%DataDIR%\ELearning\%Name%.zip
SET zipper=".\7-ZipPortable\App\7-Zip\7z.exe"
%zipper% x %zippy% -o%DataDIR%\ELearning
del /q %zippy%
%zipper% a %zippy% %DataDIR%\ELearning\%1\*
rmdir /s /q %DataDIR%\ELearning\%1
EXIT
ECHO Error > %Name%.log
EXIT

Comment: Post that as an answer, and mark it as accepted in 24 hours.